# toggle an input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#individual,#company').hide();

$('input[name=radios]:radio:checked').change(function() {
    $('#individual').toggle(this.selectedIndex === 0);
    $('#company').toggle(this.selectedIndex === 1);
});

});
</script>


<div class="radio-toolbar">
    <input type="radio"  name="radios"> 
    <input type="radio"  name="radios"> 
</div>

<div id="x">
    <form method="post" id="customForm" action="">
        <div id="individual">
            <input name="individual" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div id="company"> 
            <input name="company" type="text" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

basically i want to show only an input field. if i choose the first radio btn, then, i want display the div individual. If i choose the second radio, should be showed the company content.

thanks

demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/S5sEv/2/)

Comment: Why this code doesn't work ? is the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just added value attributes to the input

```
 <div class="radio-toolbar">
    <input type="radio" name="radios" value="i"> 
    <input type="radio" name="radios" value="c"> 
</div>

<div id="x">
    <form method="post" id="customForm" action="">
        <div id="individual">
            <input name="individual" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div id="company"> 
            <input name="company" type="text" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

... changed the selector, and compare with the aforementioned values, since the *selectedIndex* property doesn't exist in radio buttons.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#individual,#company').hide();

    $('input[name=radios]').change(function() {
      $('#individual').toggle($(this).val() === 'i');
      $('#company').toggle($(this).val() === 'c');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I would rewrite the script so the radio's have different values and use the value as the trigger instead of the === 0 / 1 construction..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#individual,#company').hide();

$("input[name='radios']").change(function() {
    switch ($(this).val()) {
      case 'ind':
          $('#individual').show();
          $('#company').hide();
      break;
      case 'comp':
          $('#individual').hide();
          $('#company').show();
      break;
    }
});

});
</script>


<div class="radio-toolbar">
    <input type="radio"  name="radios" value="ind"> 
    <input type="radio"  name="radios" value="comp"> 
</div>

<div id="x">
    <form method="post" id="customForm" action="">
        <div id="individual">
            <input name="individual" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div id="company"> 
            <input name="company" type="text" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, it works. Do you know what is the problem of my code ? I am  just curious.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if this is it, but there are a few things which feel wrong to me: I don't know if the selectedIndex property exists in javascript ( I know it's available in ASP.NET, but that isn't the same ). I also don't know if it's possible to change on a :checked element, I think the binding then would only work on the pre-selected (before script is loaded ) item.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep it simple and have the radio buttons trigger the change.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#individual').add('#company').hide();
});
</script>
<div class="radio-toolbar">
    <input type="radio" name="radios" onclick="$('#individual').show();$('#company').hide();"> Individual
    <input type="radio" name="radios" onclick="$('#company').show();$('#individual').hide();"> Company
</div>

...
```